# what does this +/- of "average" mean?

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

I have a set of data points and I was told that for it to be valid, every data point should be within +/- say 5% of the average of the entire dataset.

I have no problem of checking each data point and reach a conclusion if it is valid. My question is, how can I relate above statement to a statistic measure so that I can say, how valid it is. Put in another way, is there any relationship between the +/-5% deviation from average and the dispersion measure such as sd etc?

Thanks

Oliver

Comment: Could you provide some more context? It's not even clear to me what “valid” means here.

Comment: One (rightfully obscure) measure of dispersion of data $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ is the maximum absolute deviation from the mean, $r = \max_i\{|x_i-\overline{x}|\}$ where $\overline{x}$ is their mean. All your data are "valid," by definition, when $r\le .05\overline{x}$. That addresses your first question: yes, there is a statistical measure corresponding to this "validity" criterion.

Comment: @whuber: Gotta say, the "(rightfully obscure)" elevated this two notches in my book.

Comment: @whuber, you addressed my question perfectly. I appreciate it.